# how to add the cookie directly without refresh with php

Tags: php, cookies

i have this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    setcookie("bgcolor", $_POST['bgcolor'], time()+60*60*24, '/', httponly:true);
}

if(isset($_COOKIE['bgcolor'])) {
    $bgcolor = $_COOKIE['bgcolor'];
} else {
    $bgcolor = "gray";
}
?>
<body bgcolor="<?php echo $bgcolor; ?>">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<p>Background color:
<select name="bgcolor">
<option value="gray">Gray</option>
<option value="white">White</option>
<option value="black">Black</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
</select></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
```

cookie doesn't added without refresh, how could I change without refresh?

Comment: From PHP's manual: "_Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array._"

Comment: That code produces a "Parse error"

Comment: Assign `$bgcolor = "gray"` as default first, then do your `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` check. If you got a value in `$_POST['bgcolor']`, then assign that to `$bgcolor` now. And then perform your cookie check. Btw., this is open to cross-site scripting attacks (XSS).